# "Call to undefined method" - but I know it exists

Tags: php

This line of code:

```
echo "<strong> {$this->author->last} {$this->date->shortYear()}</strong> ...";
```

gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Date::shortYear() in /f5/debate/public/libs/Card.php  on line 22
```

Even though in Date.php (which is included in Card.php):

```
class Date {
    public $day;
    public $month;
    public $year;

    public function shortYear() {
        return substr($this->year, -2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, check that you're loading the right `Date.php` file.

Comment: I know that I am because I define a Date on line 16 ("$this->date = new Date;") without any errors.

Comment: That line is for instantiating the class. I'm referring to when you include `Date.php`. As Kalium says, more or all of `Card.php` would help.

Comment: That doesn't mean you're using the right Date class -- just that you have one.

Comment: Here's Card.php: http://pastebin.com/5yP4rLmZ

Comment: Try using an explicit path to include Data.php or drop the Date class itself into Card.php. You may not be including the Date.php you think you are.

Comment: Both of these make it work :/, but there is no other Date.php in the entire file system! What could cause this problem?

Comment: Are you sure? Check your include path. Clearly another Date class is taking precedence.

Comment: yeah it is in a directory called "lib" and using:

include '../lib/Date.php';

works...

Comment: And just a tip: using `ReflectionClass` to dump the definition of the `Date` class you're loading is a quick way to verify whether you're loading the right class.

Answer (score 4):

You're instantiating the wrong `Date` class. You can use PHP's `get_class_methods()` function to confirm which methods are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in an setup where you automatically upload your changes from your IDE to the web server your checking your pages on. It might accidentally be the case that it didn't upload the file.

Comment: How this is related to the question??

Comment: If you didn't upload your newly written function the interpreter will most probably not find it. That's how it's related. Just had this error and sratched my head for a couple of minutes till I figured my IDE might not have uploaded my changes. Which was the case...

Answer (score 0):

there is a Date class in php. So my guess is you are instantiating the wrong Date class.

Change the name of the Date class in Card.php to say myDate;

Then try again $this->date = new myDate;

See how that works.

Create a separate file to test with to remove any other stuff that may be causing confusion

DC

Ignoring charles unnecessary downvote

Another way to test this is to go into Card.php and add or ammend the constructor for Date

```
function __construct() {
        echo "created date object\n";
}
```

This will then print when you are creating the date object if it doesnt print then you know you are instantiating a different Date object.

Another method I often use is

```
$this->date = new Date;
var_dump($this->date);
```

If it shows a differnt class structure then you are expecting then again you have the wrong Date object

If not then look to see if $this->date is not redefined anywhere

e.g.

```
$this->date = new Date;

....

$this->date = new DateTime;
```

DC

Comment: The PHP date class is called `DateTime`, not Date.

Comment: Pear::Date actually http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date.examples.php Thanks for the unwarranted downvote, even if there wasnt a Date class in PHP its a valid method to test it

Comment: Charles' point is: "There is a Date class in PHP" is not the same as "There is a Date class in PEAR".

Comment: My Point is that there are classes called Date elsewhere. and it could have been included somewhere along the line. it doesn't matter whether its a php native class or a class from an extension or include. And it still doesn't warrant a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just battled this a bit.

I'm using Netbeans to code on a remote server, it turns out that for one reason or another, it wasn't syncing a file to the remote host.

This was particularly annoying because I could ctrl-click into the class and see the method, and stepping into a different method in the same class would open up the seemingly correct file.

After I discovered the issue, I simply right clicked the file and clicked 'upload.'

Answer (score 0):

You must also check the namespace used. You can have two classes with the same name, but from different namespaces. If two classes were created in the same namespace with the same name. Then what class got constructed or accessed would be dependant on the order in which they were interpreted.

Also in regard to those Date problems. If you want to access the core namespace you would reference

new \DateTime();

instead of new DateTime();

Answer (score 0):

For putting in my two cents:

It has happened to me by having two plugins in wordpress with the same namespace/class name but different methods in each:

```
/Utils/Tools
```

Deactivating one of the plugins fixed it.

The solution is to create a root namespace for each plugin:

```
/Plugin1/Utils/Tools
/Plugin2/Utils/Tools
```